# Why does the Color label of some files keep disappearing in Finder?

Tags: macos, mac, file-management, finder

In the Finder I can right-click files and give them a color label. Which is fantastic! But right now I experiencing something weird that doesn't quite make sense.

I give some files in a folder a color label, but then after a little while it seems like the color label goes away. The finder doesn't register it right away, but the files go white when I click on them. And if I do Command+A often maybe half the labels just goes away. It makes no sense! What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read that it could be caused by corrupt .DS_Store files so opened up a Terminal, went to the folder where the files were and deleted the .DS_Store file and all the ._ files.

```
rm .DS_Store
rm ._*
```

This seems to remove all the Finder file meta-data and the .DS_Store file will be rebuilt. I then re-labeled the files and so far they have stuck...

***Source:*** [Labels Not Working On my Xserve Raid thoughts?](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9487931) at [Apple Discussions](http://discussions.apple.com)

Answer (score 1):

Try seeing whether it's just a graphical glitch with the Finder, or if the labels really are disappearing - check them from the Terminal

```
mdls -name kMDItemFSLabel <filename>
```

that should give you a number > 0 if the label is still present. Then we can figure out where to look to fix it!

Comment: Forgot to check with this before I fixed it, but will try that if it happens again :)

Comment: @LoonyPandora: It happend again, and I got to check it out. And they were indeed 0. Not sure how they became zero though, cause I did make them not-zero and the Finder put color on them and everything. But anyways, my other solution fixed the issue again. Good to have this one to check with though!

Comment: Weird… I'm getting 'could not find <filename>' while the file is there and I can both read and edit it.